# render component conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import Home from "./home";
import About from "./about";
import Contact from "./contact";

const Funks = [
  {
    component: Home,
    label: "Home",
    isActive: true
  },
  {
    component: About,
    label: "About",
    isActive: false
  },
  {
    component: Contact,
    label: "Contact",
    isActive: false
  }
];

export default class Funky extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      {Funks.map(({ component, isActive}) => isActive ? /* how to render component? */ : null )}
    )
  }
}
```

How do I go about rendering the component using the component parameter? I am new to React so any tips will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: What is TABS ? And it depends on what kind of component you want to render

Comment: if ( foo ) render() {…….} else render() {….}

Comment: @TusharShahi So I have multiple files (Home, About and Contact), in each of them, I'm exporting three functions that return a bunch of text.

Comment: @HossamMaher `if ` statements don't seem to work in React ._. weird.

Comment: Put Funcks.map outside render not inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TABS.map should me Funks.map I assume.

now replace /* how to render component? */ with :

`(component === 'Home')? <Home/> : (component ==='About') ? <About/> : <Contact/>`

This will fix your current code. But it's not the ideal way to render components.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your component values inside array like following to render these components;

```
const Funks = [
  {
    component: <Home />,
    label: "Home",
    isActive: true
  },
  {
    component: <About />,
    label: "About",
    isActive: false
  },
  {
    component: <Contact />,
    label: "Contact",
    isActive: false
  }
];
```

and then map the array and output it as follows this will output your components.

```
return Funks.map((item) => (item.isActive ? item.component : null));
```

And please note that as per naming conventions the component file names must be named starting with first letter capital.